# Git fatal: failed to expand user dir in: '~.-gitignore_global'

Tags: git, git-extensions

I'm a newbie and tried to create a gitignore file, instead of that I run this command:

```
$ git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

I don't see my repo anymore, please send help.

Don't know what to do.

Comment: What does "I don't see my repo anymore" even mean? How is this related to github and/or git-extensions?

Comment: my repository is in git ext and when i open it it shows: this repository does not yet contain any commits

Comment: I don’t think that’s the exact command you ran, or perhaps you ran it in some strange shell. The title suggests you managed to set `core.excludesfile` to `~.-gitignore_global` and now Git is not happy. Just remove that line from your Git config file.